# Does the Cpanel resource usage monitor show just the local package or global?

Tags: resources, cpanel

the CPU usage monitor in a shared web-hosting Cpanel shows it constantly hitting 100%.

This website has little traffic (500 uniques per day). So it seems unusual to be this high.

There are around 50 other websites hosted on this (shared) Virtual Private Server.

I wonder if the high CPU load has to stem from this website, or if it may stem from one of the other websites that are also hosted on this shared (VPS) server?

Some screenshots:

[resource usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68VX8.png)

[cpanel detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6j0KE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your site is NOT hitting any CPU limit, You have setup 100% cpu for your cPanel user and currently your site is using 0%.

Also cPanel resource usage is only showing single user/site stats, it's not showing global stats of your server.

Comment: It is constantly hitting the 100% CPU limit.  Please see resource usage screenshot.